# Unity (C#) - UI Image RectTransform width always returns 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I do the following:

```
Debug.Log(xpBar.rect.width);
```

it gives me 0. Every time. The gameobject is active when its trying to access it.
[image]

Comment: If we're being honest it's probably not a bug in `RectTransform`, we'll need more info than a contextless line to help.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Do not post code as an image.

Answer (score 0):

you use 'Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();' in first line of your code.
it's work fine for me